# URL Rewrite /foobar/rss to rss.php?username=foobar

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I already use URL Rewriting to rewrite `/foobar` to `index.php?username=foobar` using:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What should I add to also rewrite `/foobar/rss` to `rss.php?username=foobar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it's done:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/rss$ /rss.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```